# WPF UserControls: Have a Command that is only available internally in the UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls, command

I'm doing an WPF `UserControl`.

Inside of this UserControl, I've several `Button` that can be used on certains conditions, so binding them to a command is perfect.

The command called by those Buttons should not be available outside of the UserControl.

If I make my Commands private, the XAML of the `UserControl` says that he wants public member.

So, what is the way to go to have one UserControl that has several commands internally, but not available outside of the UserControl?

Example:

```
<Wizard CanGoPrevious="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty}">
    <WizardPage>
        <TextBlock>Page one</TextBlock>
    </WizardPage>
</Wizard>
```

Wizard's XAML:

```
<DockPanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type wizard:Wizard}}}" LastChildFill="True">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"> 
        <Button Content="{Binding PreviousButtonText}" Command="{Binding GoToPreviousPageCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentControl ></ContentControl>
</DockPanel>
```

Wizard's Code behind:

```
//Protected doesn't work. Also, this command should not be available outside of the Wizard `UserControl`
protected DelegateCommand GoToPreviousPageCommand { get; set; }
```

Which is assigned like this in the constructor

```
GoToPreviousPageCommand = new DelegateCommand(GoToPreviousPage, CanGoToPreviousPage);


    private void GoToPreviousPage()
    {
        //[...]
    }

    private bool CanGoToNextPage()
    {
        //Some usage of the Wizard's DP:
        return CanGoPrevious //&& some other stuff
    }
```

Comment: Don't bother.  It's a user control--it's perfectly fine to include logic pertaining to the UI in the codebehind.

Comment: @Will Ok, but it's not find to provide an UserControl with public access to commands that have to be available internally only.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : adding sample code (should be able to copy/past/run):
Leave command as public, but make your ViewModel internal will make the command invisible to the outside code!

```
<Window x:Class="InternalCommandUsageSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InternalCommandUsageSample"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<local:MyUserControl/>
```

code behind the window that tests user control:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace InternalCommandUsageSample
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        var vm = new MyViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

}

user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="InternalCommandUsageSample.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <Button Content="Test Me" Command="{Binding TestMeCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and the internal view model that is not visible outside your assembly:

```
internal class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _message = "click the button";
    private DelegateCommand _cmd;

    public DelegateCommand TestMeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _cmd ?? (_cmd = new DelegateCommand(cmd => { Message = "Your button click envoked an internal command"; }));
        }
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set
        {
            if (_message != value)
            {
                _message = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Message");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

EDIT: addtional question was asked in comments on how to use dependency property of the suer control and a view model. There are many ways, this is one of them:

```
        public string MySampleDependencyProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MySampleDependencyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MySampleDependencyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MySampleDependencyPropertyProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("MySampleDependencyProperty", typeof(string), 
        typeof(MyUserControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, (o, e) => ((MyUserControl)o).OnMySampleDependencyPropertyChanged()));

    private void OnMySampleDependencyPropertyChanged()
    {
        viewMdoel.WhateverProperty = MySampleDependencyProperty;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, it means this is editable from inside the library, but it's acceptable. Initially I would like to create a ViewModel, but I didn't had the feeling it was possible with `DependencyProperties`, am I wrong?

Comment: post a bit of your code so I can see what you are talking about. Because with a ViewModel you don't need Dependency Properties, you can have regular properties as long as they raise propertyChanged event. Also a Command can (or usually) have a private setter, so it is not editable.

Comment: What part of code you want to see? The thing is that within the windows where we will use this `UserControl`, some properties(of the UserControl) will be bound to properties of the MainWindow's ViewModel. And within my UserControl, I need some values of those bound values

Comment: I added some code. Also, I tried to put the command as internal but it seems that Visual studio is still not happy. VS is telling me that it is expected a Public member, and if I launch it, I got a BindingExpression path error

Comment: I will type something up here in a bit

Comment: I added some code that you should be able to run, it's dead simple and should give you the idea how to build a user control and still use MVVM without exposing internal guts of the logic that you don't want to share with users, good luck

Comment: Thank you, seems nice, but I've still one question, my UserControl needs to have some Dependencies Properties, how do you make them work with your ViewModel?

Comment: sorry long weekend, just saw your msg, and added more code sample for you regarding your last question